# Table JOIN and CREATE new table extremely slow

Tags: mysql, join, table, aws, ctas

I'm using something like this to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE result AS 
(SELECT calls.*, 
      targ_with_planned_calls.*
 FROM calls
      INNER JOIN planned
              ON calls.first_id = planned.another_id);
```

The two tables have around 60k and 80k rows. One table has 5 columns and the other around 15. I'm using AWS RDS db.t2.medium instance. I've let this query run for as long as 10 minutes and it's still going.

Should this be taking so long? I'm wondering what the performance issue is. I would have thought it would be fairly quick.

Comment: Try to use specific `column names` instead of `SELECT *`. You may use `CREATE table LIKE` followed by INSERT will be much faster

Comment: I guess the `SELECT ... targ_with_planned_calls.*` should be `SELECT ... planned.*`. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing DDL along with the SELECT

Doing `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` mechanically does two commands

- CREATE TABLE
- INSERT INTO ... SELECT

This will produce locks on both `calls` and `planned`

I have written about this behavior in some of my older posts

- `Mar 23, 2012` : [MySQL Locks while CREATE TABLE AS SELECT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15461/mysql-locks-while-create-table-as-select/15479#15479)
- `Aug 08, 2014` : [MySQL consistent nonlocking reads vs. INSERT ... SELECT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73540/mysql-consistent-nonlocking-reads-vs-insert-select/73542#73542)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have neither index:

On `calls` an INDEX or PRIMARY KEY starting with `first_id`

Ditto for `planned`.`another_id`

You need one or the other to keep from doing  60k *times* 80k  operations.  With an index, it will be only  60k *plus* 80k operations.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to confirm, and to let us check for other issues such as dissimilar datatypes.