# Is there any particular reason LIMIT 0 is allowed?

Tags: mysql

I've just tried running `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 0`, which unsurprisingly, returns 0 results.

I could see an argument for making it be an error, because it will never return any result, but then again it isn't invalid like `LIMIT 'HelloWorld'`.

Are there any actual real-world use cases for `LIMIT 0`, or is it just allowed because there's no real reason to *not* to allow it?

Comment: I never thought about this - interesting question. Can a `LIMIT` be a parameter (which could be 0) - or a subselect i.e. `SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM bar`?`+1 for interesting question.

Comment: Tested - it doesn't appear to allow either parameter or select - bug?

Comment: Yeah it seemed weird, I can't possibly think of a use case for `LIMIT 0`, but it might just be the case of "Because `LIMIT 0` doesn't break anything" so no point making it illegal.

Comment: Such a query (as well as many others , e.g.  `WHERE 1=0` )  will return column metadata.

Comment: Ahh, so it's a way to get things like the column names without bringing back unneeded data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a matter of convenience

I once answered a post [Table JOIN and CREATE new table extremely slow](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101325/table-join-and-create-new-table-extremely-slow/101332#101332), mentioning how `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` will create a table and then perform `INSERT INTO SELECT` to populate the table

There are ways to use `LIMIT 0` to create a temp table without indexes

```
CREATE TABLE mytable SELECT * FROM othertable LIMIT 0;
```

In another post, [MySQL Locks while CREATE TABLE AS SELECT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15461/mysql-locks-while-create-table-as-select/15479#15479), I mentioned under `OPTION #2` using `WHERE 1=2` as a way to create a blank temp table with no indexes

```
CREATE TABLE 1_temp_foo SELECT * FROM crm_companies WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE 1_temp_foo ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In terms of end result, using `LIMIT 0` and `WHERE 1=2` and even `WHERE 0` are synonymous.

I agree with your assumption that it was allowed for no particular reason (because there's no real reason to not allow it, as you say), but it sure comes in handy for such occasions.